# dropbox api error occured in Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, dropbox-api

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\beproject\vendor\dropbox\dropbox-sdk\lib\Dropbox\Curl.php on line 71

Comment: You have given us nothing to go on. Please post the code that is generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the '**max_execution_time**' to 120 or higher, this can be found on xampp\php\php.ini
2. Change the '**$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']**' to 120 or higher, this can be found on xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php
3. Restart your XAMP to regenerate the phpinfo.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I had the same problem, but this, didn't fix it now i get this message: 'Empty reply from server'.